# On Linear Separation, I can't understand this

Tags: graph, computer-science

[image]

[image]

I don't understand what I'm supposed to do here. I am getting confused by the three values stated at the start: 0.5, 0.5, 1.1. Can someone guide me through?

Comment: Can you read your question ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The goal of Linear Separation is to tell two feature classes, the red and blue dots, apart by the mean of a line<sup>1</sup>.

Compare the original data-set with this one:

[image: The XOR problem]

clearly it [cannot be linearly separated](http://www.ece.utep.edu/research/webfuzzy/docs/kk-thesis/kk-thesis-html/node19.html).
The original one can be easily separated though, there are infinite lines that will do the job.
To explicitly show the separability the text gives the specific line<sup>2</sup> *r* passing thought the points *P*(0.5, -0.5) and *Q*(1, 1).

You can convince yourself the *r* separates the classes by drawing it

[image: Separating line]

The points *P* and *Q* have been found empirically and the values 0.5, -0.5, 1, 1 are their coordinates.
Notes that you dropped a minus from the second "0.5" and misinterpreted the second coordinate pair "1, 1" as the number "1.1".

---

<sup>1</sup> Actually a Separation surface in n-dimensional problems.
<sup>2</sup> I gave the various entities names. The original formulation was a bit sloppy IMO.

Comment: Thank you very much Margaret